# Why do I get "address boundary error" from this piece of assembly code

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86, x86-64

The code is generated by a compiler that I am working on. However I have no idea why it is giving me this error. There is no register conflict. When I try to invoke `callq   *%rbx` my program immediately crash and I get an error saying "**terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)**"

I understand that it seems like the program tries to access illegal memory but i can't tell where it is wrong. Can anyone please give me a hint?

**EDIT**: the completed assembly code is [here](https://gist.github.com/thejackz/d0d1cba0f0fe4e56799ec5b4c653aa94), and the code my compiler tries to compile is [here](https://gist.github.com/thejackz/209fcf3c86d73716931c127b14f8122d). The runtime.c is [here](https://gist.github.com/thejackz/c785ed8e6c7334a4e4596e0869484b90)

```
    .globl _main
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r13
    subq    $0, %rsp
    movq    $16384, %rdi
    movq    $16, %rsi
    callq   _initialize
    movq    _rootstack_begin(%rip), %r15

    leaq    o13352(%rip),   %rbx
    leaq    z13351(%rip),   %rcx
    movq    $1, %rdi
    callq   *%rcx              <------ As noted in comments: z13351() clobbers %rbx
    movq    %rax,   %rcx
    movq    $20,    %rdi
    movq    %rcx,   %rsi
    callq   *%rbx       <-------------      (Address boundary error)

    ...
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using register-indirect `call` instructions instead of [the usual `call rel32`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) encoding?  Are you reusing the same code that your compiler uses when emitting loads/stores for globals?

Comment: What's in `%rbx` when your `call` happens?  Did the previous function call maybe clobber `%rbx` (violating the calling convention, at least if you're using one of the standard ones).  Is it the address of executable memory?  If this a JIT-compiler, did you remember to make sure the memory is executable?  On some systems, malloc and static allocations aren't from executable pages by default.  If that's not the problem, did you get the encoding correct for the RIP-relative `lea`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, in my compiler I annotate all functions with `function-ref` tag so I can distinguish them from local variables. And sorry I don't really understand your second question. What globals are you referring to ?

Comment: I'm trying to guess why your compiler would generate such dumb code, instead of emitting `call o15954`.  A register-indirect `call` after loading a RIP-relative address into a register is totally braindead (and a waste of branch-prediction resources).  Obviously your compiler is still in the very early stages, so braindead code is to be expected, but it's worth pointing out.  (See the performance links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), esp. Agner Fog's stuff.)  But anyway, you're going to need to use a debugger.  That's essential.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know why you say it is dumb. I follow a compiler course and write that compiler. I never intended to make it a production compiler.

Comment: Indirect branches are well known to be detrimental to performance.  It also wastes a register.  The code size is also way worse, and it takes more instructions.  The efficient alternative is the normal way to call functions by their label is with `call o15954`, so the code your compiler emits is way overcomplicating things compared to what you'd see in even un-optimized gcc output.  It's ok for a toy compiler to generate terrible code, but it's a good idea to recognize that fact.  I'm not calling you dumb, just the asm that your compiler emits.

Comment: You still haven't added anything to address my second comment.  Did using `call o15954` fix your problem?  If not, the question doesn't contain enough information for us to debug it for you.  It's not a [mcve] because we don't know what's at `o15954`, and whether it has execute permission, or whether one of your functions clobbers `%rbx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, I've been debugging it for a while. `%rbx` is modified when function return from `z15953`, but I could not figure out what is causing it. I added some new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code segfaults because `%rbx` is no longer pointing to the right place after the first function returns.  So instead of calling `o13352`, you jump to some address which isn't mapped.  Code-fetch and loads/stores both `SIGSEGV` on invalid addresses.

---

You probably need to fix the `%rbx` clobbering, but that's a separate question.  The best answer to this one is to **emit calls to named symbols with direct `call` insns**, instead of using the convoluted function-calling sequence of a RIP-relative LEA and an indirect CALL.

```
...               # set up args
call    z13351
...               # set up args
call    o13352
```

It's simpler for the compiler to generate, is **much easier for a human to follow** (helpful while debugging other issues), and makes the code significantly more efficient: doesn't waste a register, smaller code size, fewer instructions, and avoids branch mispredicts from the indirect branches (which you should use for function pointers of jump tables, but not for this).

See the links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more performance and other stuff. esp. [Agner Fog's guides](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) are a great resource for how to write create good and correct asm.  Of course, a toy compiler isn't expected to generate good code, but it's a good idea to know something about what's good and what's bad.  Agner Fog's guide will probably also help you understand things better which will help with generating correct code, regardless of efficiency.

---

If you want to keep using indirect calls through function pointers even when not necessary:

**According to your comments, `z15953` doesn't preserve `%rbx`**.  (or `z13351` or whatever it's called in this update of your code).  Assuming that's a bug, fixing that will also fix this, since the code in your question looks correct (but nasty).

You didn't specify what ABI your compiler is trying to generate code for, but I assume it's a calling convention where `%rbx` is supposed to be call-preserved (aka callee saved aka non-volatile).   So fixing that bug is probably necessary for other reasons, even if you change your function-call sequence to use normal direct CALLs.

It looks like you push/pop `%rbx` in functions you generate to save/restore it.  Reduce this to as simple a case as possible that still demonstrates this problem.  The code you linked to in your question is too big to even include in-line, so it's obviously not even close to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and no, I'm not interested in wading through that mess, sorry.  You wrote your compiler, so you probably have an easier time than me recognizing the patterns of what the bloated code is doing and finding the parts that might be relevant.)

Since your function still manages to `ret` successfully, that means you didn't break the stack (i.e. reach a `ret` along a path that doesn't include the epilogue `pop`s).  But maybe you overwrote the saved value of `%rbx` on the stack?  Did you reserve enough space with `sub $size, %rsp` before using rsp-relative addresses to store temporaries?

---

#### Stupid Band-aid fix:

Schedule the `lea` of the second address after the `call`.

```
# your original:
leaq    o13352(%rip),   %rbx
leaq    z13351(%rip),   %rcx
...
callq   *%rcx
...                             # set up args
callq   *%rbx
```

```
# what you should do instead:
...
leaq    z13351(%rip),   %rcx
callq   *%rcx
...                             # set up args
leaq    o13352(%rip),   %rcx
callq   *%rcx
```

This saves a register by reusing the same one for function-pointer setup, instead of a different register for every function you're going to call.  (Which obviously doesn't scale to functions that call many other functions.)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I will change to direct `call` instr when I finish all the features I planned to implement and pass all tests as the test code is provided by the course i am following. The test code(an interpreter) assume me use indirect-call.